# Can a Mac OS X file be opened and modified remotely on a shutdown system?

Tags: macos

ln tracing the activity of a file in a Mac OS, I saw on one file which showed that it was opened and modified yesterday.

I did not use my computer at all yesterday. It was shutdown.

So does it mean someone accessed my computer remotely?

Comment: Has your pc been in sleep mode yesterday or was is really turned off?

Comment: It was shut down completely.

Comment: Is it a system file or a file that has been created by you?

Comment: It was a Word document which I created.

Comment: Where do you get the change date from? Filesystem or from the metadata of the document?

Comment: In reference to this question, I also have files that I created a week ago and when I went to view its log activity, I saw that the last modify date on a different file said Sept 1969.  Yes, 1969.  Before there were even Mac comps.  How does this happen?

Comment: By doing Get Info, and then reviewing Modify, Created, and Last Opened logs.

Comment: A timestamp like Sept 1969 can be caused by a software error. Unix TImestamps are stored in seconds since the 1. January of 1970 so if some program sets a negative value you can get a result like september 1969. Do you have any backup or archiving software installed or some anti virus software or any other software that "looks at" or touches all files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30116/discussion-between-user7149-and-davidb).

Comment: It looks like all signs point to my computer having been accessed physically.

Comment: @user7149: So as to get relevant answers, please mention within your original question the fact that your Mac was **shutdown**, and the fact that you have files dated before 1970.

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac was **shutdown** yesterday, then no file could have been really modified yesterday (neither locally nor remotely). Your file were modified, but neither **yesterday** nor **remotely**.

The origin of your problem is a wrong setting of time (either the time itself i.e. GMT, or the timezone). Hence an event dated as ocuring yesterday might have happened in fact the day before or today, or even on a completly different year.

This explain also events dated on 1969.

You should investigate this completly different problem, because a wrong time may cause a lot of errors on any system, and not only just date where file were modified.

Comment: where would I go to check the time settings on my system?  I'm looking at my time now and it looks correct.  If I save a file now, it'll save it with the correct time.

Comment: This is a completly different question, and I advise you to start such a question with a right title. For example: "How to invistigate time problem on MacOS X". The best discussion group to ask this question is: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You have _nor_ and _neither_ reversed. ​ ​